# Drawables Turning Red in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

My drawables in android studio are turning red and are not displaying. Does anyone know what could be causing this?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

It appears you have Version Control Integration enabled, and those files simply aren't added. If you open the Version Control panel, you should see "Unversioned Files". Expand that, and you can right-click and select "Add" to add them to your version control system.

Alternatively, do it on the command line, i.e. if you're using git:

```
git add <path-to-file>
```